# Is it safe in Perl to delete a key from a hash reference when I loop on the same hash? And why?

Tags: perl, hash, key

I basically want to do this:

```
foreach my $key (keys $hash_ref) {

    Do stuff with my $key and $hash_ref

    # Delete the key from the hash
    delete $hash_ref->{$key};
}
```

Is it safe? And why?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're not iterating over the hash, you're iterating over the list of keys returned by `keys` before you even started looping. Keep in mind that

```
for my $key (keys %$hash_ref) {
   ...
}
```

is roughly the same as

```
my @anon = keys %$hash_ref;
for my $key (@anon) {
   ...
}
```

Deleting from the hash causes no problem whatsoever.

---

[`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html), on the other, does iterate over a hash. Each time it's called, `each` returns a different element. Yet, it's still safe to `delete` the current element!

```
# Also safe
while (my ($key) = each(%$hash_ref)) {
   ...
   delete $hash_ref->{$key};
   ...
}
```

> If you add or delete a hash's elements while iterating over it, entries may be skipped or duplicated--so don't do that. Exception: It is always safe to delete the item most recently returned by each()

Comment: The wording "in the current implementation" scares me a little, because it sounds like there's space there to change the implementation such that it is no longer safe. I wouldn't rely on that, but then I wouldn't use `each()` either - foreach keys is fine.

Comment: @LeoNerd, older Perl (at least 5.10) just say "It is always safe to delete..." For obvious compatibility reasons, I doubt this will ever be changed without introducing some `use feature` or other similar pragma.

Comment: who added that "in the current implementation"?  it wasn't always there, and shouldn't be there now, unless there's a really really good reason.  update: Doesn't seem to be there anymore.

Comment: ah.  added in http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/bade7fbcf63fdefa0b4fd8a0321087860e413483, removed in http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/d8021140df0281e134cb4ff987fcb69319fa11a5

Answer (score 3):

It is safe, because `keys %hash` provides entire list once, before you start iterating. `foreach` then continues to work on this pre-generated list, no matter what you change inside actual hash.

It eats up your memory though, because you keep entire list until you've done.