# Is it safe to modify a hash while traversing the result of keys %hash?

Tags: perl

Is it safe to modify a hash while traversing the list resulting from `keys %hash`?

```
my $blah;
my %hash;

for my $key (keys %hash)
{
  # Some code that sets $blah....
  delete $hash{$key} if $key=~/$blah/;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853835/is-it-safe-in-perl-to-delete-a-key-from-a-hash-reference-when-i-loop-on-the-same

Comment: Thanks, I'll vote to close...